# Safesenders List exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange-2010

Can i add to safe senders list from the exchange 2010 console or does this need to be done on the users outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs more information/clarification, but if you're talking about the safe senders list in *Outlook*, then no, that's not possible from the Exchange console (and is, frankly, an unreasonably huge PITA to do with scripts or GPOs or the like).

The solution I've encountered most frequently is to completely disable the Junk Mail folder with a GPO, and handle unwanted email with whatever the corporate mail filter/anti-spam solution is.

Comment: Thanks that was what i meant i think i will try the doing it from GPO as you said

Comment: @ben950 Word of caution - it's easy to create/define a safe sender list *for everyone*, but just appending or removing a value from an existing list is a nightmare, so be careful, and don't try it out on any VIPs or technical illiterates until you've got it down cold, or you'll be sorry.

Comment: i would only test it for myself first before rolling it out. Thanks